# spark 2.1.1 error in read/write to redshift on EMR

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

Trying to read/write from/to redshift (data in s3). But getting weird error when accessing the data frame. I could see the data frame is getting created and it is able to access the data since it outputs the column names of the table

```
scala> :require /home/hadoop/spark-redshift_2.10-2.0.1.jar
Added '/home/hadoop/spark-redshift_2.10-2.0.1.jar' to classpath.

scala> :require /home/hadoop/RedshiftJDBC41-1.2.12.1017.jar
Added '/home/hadoop/RedshiftJDBC41-1.2.12.1017.jar' to classpath.

scala> :require /home/hadoop/spark-avro_2.11-3.2.0.jar
Added '/home/hadoop/spark-avro_2.11-3.2.0.jar' to classpath.

scala>   val read_data = (spark.read
     |     .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
     |     .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://redshifthost/schema?user=admin&password=password")
     |     .option("query", "SELECT * FROM schema.table LIMIT 1")
     |     .option("tempdir", tempS3Dir)
     |     .option("forward_spark_s3_credentials",true)
     |     .load())
read_data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [aid: int, uid: int ... 3 more fields]

scala> read_data.count()
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of
>   scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of
>   type scala.collection.Seq in instance of
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2133)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2251)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
>     at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
>     at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Driver stacktrace:   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1493)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1492)
>   at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48) 
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1492)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
>   at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1720)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1675)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1664)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:629)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1925)   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1938)   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1965)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:275)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2386)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2788)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2385)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2392)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2420)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2419)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withCallback(Dataset.scala:2801)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2419)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was either on how I was importing the packages or the version of the packages that I was using. Below way of installing packages worked like a charm

```
./bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0,com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:2.0.1,com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0 --jars /home/hadoop/RedshiftJDBC41-1.2.12.1017.jar
```